# Is there a way to prevent the VLP-16 from disconnecting after it starts delivering information?

Tags: ros, vlp-16, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I connect the VLP-16, the connection works fine, but after a few minutes Ubuntu indicates that the connection has been disconnected.

These are the commands I input into the terminal to get a data feed.

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
sudo ip addr add 192.168.1.200 dev eth0 
sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch  calibration:=/home/user/PUCK_Calibration.yaml
```

I need the connection to be stable between the laptop and the LIDAR for a very long time. Is there a stable way to establish a connection? Because when it disconnects, I need to rerun those commands to get data from the lidar again.

Am I doing something wrong?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LST with ROS Indigo.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248332/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-the-vlp-16-from-disconnecting-after-it-starts-delivering-information?/) by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2016-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-18**:
Are you on a wireless network? Or a network with a DHCP server that has a very short lease-time?

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2016-11-18**:
I am on a wireless network. Do I need to turn off wifi while connected to the LIDAR?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-18**:
No, as your lidar is on a wired connection it should not matter. I was just wondering if frequent disconnects on your wireless might trigger a DHCP release/renew cycle. That could result in loss of routes, leading to what you described.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-18**:
In general though: unless you need your `eth0` for something else, why not just configure it with a static IP? No need to fiddle with `ip addr` and adding routes.

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2016-11-18**:
I'll give that a shot. I was having trouble before when I wasn't fiddling with the `ip addr` but I'll see if I can make it work with just a static IP.

I was following [this answer.](http://answers.ros.org/question/244445/having-problems-with-velodyne-vlp-16-and-ros/?answer=245108#post-id-245108)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-19**:
Please just accept your own answer instead of closing the question with just some comments. That will more clearly mark this question as answered. Thanks.

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2016-11-19**:
If you don't mind, could you write the answer out. I don't have enough points to accept my own answer yet. I'll accept yours and close it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-19**:
I've accepted it for you. Good to hear you got things to work.

**Comment by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) on 2016-11-19**:
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I checked the wired connection settings and it seems like it was set to Automatic (DHCP). It works now that I set it to manual and input the ip and mask. Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [kparikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28560/kparikh/) with karma: 53 on 2016-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1